# Python global variable empty in function

Tags: python, global

So I've got a couple global variables: `directory_name` and `file_list`

They're defined at the top and then I give them values in main. I need their values in a function called `checkDirectory(blocknum)`. If I print their values before I call the function, they're correct, but in the function they are empty. This is some of the code:

```
file_list = []
directory_name = ""

def checkDirectory(blocknum):
    global directory_name
    global file_list
    directory = tokenize(open(directory_name + '/' + file_list[blocknum], 'r').read())

main():
    try:
        directory_name = sys.argv[1] 
        if not os.path.exists(directory_name):
            print("This is not a working directory.")
            return
    except:
        directory_name = os.getcwd()

    files = os.listdir(directory_name)
    file_list = sorted(files, key=lambda x: int((x.split("."))[1].strip()))
    ....
    checkDirectory(26)
```

This is a basic 100 line script, and I can pass in the variables but I'll have to do that for three or four functions which will be recursive, so I'd rather not have to do it every time.

Comment: Probably need more here to help... what does the code that sets the values look like, and are they referenced anywhere else? Note that for anything more complex than a throwaway script you're better off with a class than with globals.

Comment: Why can't you also pass them to the function?  And you would only pass directory_name and file_list[blocknum]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are shadowing `directory_name` and `file_list` in your main function. Since those variables are not known in that scope, they get created locally. In order to operate on the global variables, you need to declare them global in your `main()` as well:

```
file_list = []
directory_name = ""

def checkDirectory(blocknum):
    global directory_name
    global file_list
    directory = tokenize(open(directory_name + '/' + file_list[blocknum], 'r').read())

main():
    global directory_name
    global file_list
    ...
```

Please remember that, as mentioned in the comments, using globals is not good practice and can lead to bad code in the long run (in terms of unreadable/unmaintainable/buggy).

Comment: In this case, how would you solve this problem without using global variables?